# how can I have a item with background 100% width of the oj-panel

Tags: css, oracle-jet

Currently have a oj-panel with another oj-panel inside but I want that, the second one to have the background color covered till the border of the first one... [current state of project](http://prntscr.com/ik0klx)

Current code:

```
<div class="oj-panel" style="border-style: solid; border-color: lightgrey;">
<div class="oj-panel" style="background-color: lightgrey">
    <span data-bind="text: oj.Translations.getTranslatedString('application.name')"/>
</div>
```

[example of what I want to implement](http://prntscr.com/ik0l55)

Is the oj-panel the best way to go? If so, how can I have the background covered til the borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding from the parent `div`, margins on your child div and use `width: 100%` on your child div.

Try:

```
.oj-panel {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the inner div and put the background color on the outer div.

I’m curious why you don’t just use alt-1 though
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=panel&demo=panelcolors

```
<div class="oj-panel oj-panel-alt1">
    <span data-bind="text: oj.Translations.getTranslatedString('application.name')"/>
</div>
```